# sudo: unable to mkdir /var/log/sudo-io/00/2A: No space left on device

Tags: linux, sudo, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

A script began throwing errors related to not being able to init an I/O plugin sudoers_io: (amazon linux).

I can't get into delete some logs since each time I use the sudo command, it fails to log that I used the command (I am guessing here). Any ideas on how to free up space or delete/rotate the logs?

Output below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx log]$ sudo bash
sudo: unable to mkdir /var/log/sudo-io/00/2A: No space left on device
sudo: error initializing I/O plugin sudoers_io



[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx log]$ du -s * | sort -nr | head
du: cannot read directory ‘audit’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory ‘sudo-io’: Permission denied
16092   secure
2188    secure-20180401
640 messages-20180325
640 messages-20180318
636 messages-20180401
636 messages-20180311
196 cloud-init.log
160 wtmp
132 messages
104 dracut.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently have enabled full output logging in sudo(ers).

The easiest way to free space, probably deleting the `sudo` logs, is either logging as `root`, or using `su`, if your configurations allow it.

Depending on how much `/var/log` is full, those procedures might or might not be successful.  On the worst case, booting in single mode or from a live system will allow you to clean up things.

Unless you have very specific needs to log so much of `sudo` operations, I would edit `/etc/sudoers` to change the logging setup. Having such a verbose setup will exhaust quickly again the available space.

Comment: Thanks. I had to find sacrifice lots of cached anaconda packages, but after deleting I was able to sudo bash my way back to clearing these sudo-io log files.

Answer (score 3):

You are hitting likely only the symptoms of a wrong configured sudoers file.

If you `tail /var/log/sudo.log` and see all the time the same command, you should add the sudo options `NOLOG_INPUT: NOLOG_OUTPUT:`.

Example:

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: NOLOG_INPUT: NOLOG_OUTPUT: /usr/bin/mycommand, /usr/bin/secondcommand
```

However, if you manage a large scale setup with many Servers I suggest to set also the following in the /etc/sudoers file:

```
Defaults  maxseq=1000
```

Caveat:

- This setting is only supported by version 1.8.7 or higher
- This Option is listed in the "Strings" Section in the manual, which is obviously wrong. It's an integer value that you have to provide.

Further Infos:

- [Redhat Post on how to do it (if you have a login)](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5882221)
- [Sudoers Manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.10/sudoers.man.html)
- [Discussion about how to use it properly](https://mailing.unix.sudo-users.narkive.com/VvJYrN8Y/sudo-users-rotating-logs)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this problem in case you have free space in the disk (did you check with `df -h`?) is a problem with inodes. Just run `df -i` to check inodes usage, for example check var partition here...

```
[root@test-kompjuteras ~]# df -hi
Filesystem                   Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root   313K  9.5K  304K    4% /
tmpfs                          984K     1  984K    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                      126K    44  125K    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_var    250K  250K     0  100% /var
```

If you have 100% somewhere - you will need to delete some files or to move them on other partition or other storage.